# How to scrape google map in python without using selenium and any api?

Tags: python, google-maps, beautifulsoup, python-requests, screen-scraping

Scrape google map using only requests and 'bs4' library.

I dont want any suggestions regarding using selenium or api.

1. selenium is too slow and use lots of memory.
2. Api is good choice but it is costly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using just requests and bs4 is hard but possible. Not entirely sure what information you are trying to parse, but this should help you:

```py
import requests, lxml, re, json
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

headers = {
    "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/70.0.3538.102 Safari/537.36 Edge/18.19582"
}

# works with different countries, languages
params = {
    "q": "mcdonalds",
    "gl": "jp",
    "hl": "ja", # japanese
}

response = requests.get("https://www.google.com/search", headers=headers, params=params)
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'lxml')

local_results = []

for result in soup.select('.VkpGBb'):
  title = result.select_one('.dbg0pd span').text
  try:
      website = result.select_one('.yYlJEf.L48Cpd')['href']
  except:
      website = None

  try:
      directions = f"https://www.google.com{result.select_one('.yYlJEf.VByer')['data-url']}"
  except:
      directions = None
      
  address_not_fixed = result.select_one('.lqhpac div').text
  # removes phone number from "address_not_fixed" variable
  # https://regex101.com/r/cwLdY8/1
  address = re.sub(r' · ?.*', '', address_not_fixed)
  phone = ''.join(re.findall(r' · ?(.*)', address_not_fixed))
  
  try:
      hours = result.select_one('.dXnVAb').previous_element
  except:
      hours = None

  try:
      options = result.select_one('.dXnVAb').text.split('·')
  except:
      options = None

  local_results.append({
      'title': title,
      'phone': phone,
      'address': address,
      'hours': hours,
      'options': options,
      'website': website,
      'directions': directions,
  })

print(json.dumps(local_results, indent=2, ensure_ascii=False))
```

Here is the output that you will get back, hopefully this helps!:

```py
# English results:
   {
    "title": "McDonald's",
    "phone": "(620) 251-3330",
    "address": "Coffeyville, KS",
    "hours": " ⋅ Opens 5AM",
    "options": [
      "Curbside pickup",
      "Delivery"
    ],
    "website": "https://www.mcdonalds.com/us/en-us/location/KS/COFFEYVILLE/302-W-11TH/4581.html?cid=RF:YXT:GMB::Clicks",
    "directions": "https://www.google.com/maps/dir//McDonald's,+302+W+11th+St,+Coffeyville,+KS+67337/data=!4m6!4m5!1m1!4e2!1m2!1m1!1s0x87b784f6803e4c81:0xf5af9c9c89f19918?sa=X&hl=en&gl=us"
  }
```